# Spring access saved file without restarting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

A file is generated dynamically at run time through one of the methods and is persisted in `resources`. As soon as the file is generated, the server automatically restarts as it detects a change in the File System.

Although, I know it's an anti pattern to save the file in the project directory itself, but the project demands of such feature and there is no escape at the moment.

Is there any way to prevent the restart of the server if any of the files are generated / modified specifically in `resources`; i.e. Ignoring the `resources` directory.

Build tool is `Maven` and editor: `Intellij`.

Can `spring-boot-devtools` be the reason for the restart? I tried adding `spring.devtools.restart.enabled:  false` in `property.yml` file but without any luck.

Comment: where do you save the file? how do you deploy&start your application?

Comment: I save my files in my resource folder. resources/files. Deploy my application local with maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should save the file somewhere outside your project mainly because `resource` folder is a standard maven folder and it's bundled into the war when you deploy. When you save a file it's saved into the file system only. However the file won't be available in your already packaged war bundle. That's why you are able to see the files after you restart, they will be bundled into the new war every time you restart because maven recompiles them and put them into new war.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So create a new folder outside the standard maven folder would be the solution? :-)

Comment: @1thingtodo yes, I think so. please let us know about it :)

Comment: It works. I save it in my target folder!

Comment: @1thingtodo please keep in mind that `mvn clear` will remove everything in target folder along with your saved files.